# How do I get this with only One Query/SubQuery

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this database table:

```
Name   Beneficiary   GenderBeneficiary
---------------------------------------
Karla  Karla         Female
Carl   Mandy         Female
Mark   Lu            Male
Erik   Math          Male
Jhon   Jhon          Male
```

And I need this

```
Gender

Description Male        Female        Total
-------------------------------------------
Employee     1           1             2
Familiar     2           1             3
Total        3           2             5
```

If the name is the same of the beneficiary is an `Employee`, if not is a familiar.

I get a nice result using `UNION` with 4 queries and the structure in SQL Server is:

**Updated:** stored procedure used

```
USE [BdDiscountCardSystem] 
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ONGO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FillTableOne]
    @dateStart DATETIME,
    @dateEnd DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        COUNT (GenderBeneficiary) AS Gender
    FROM
        CartaDescuento
    WHERE
        Name = BeneficiaryName
        AND GenderBeneficiary = 'Male'
        AND DateS BETWEEN @dateStart AND @dateEnd

    UNION

    SELECT
        COUNT (GenderBeneficiary)
    FROM
        CartaDescuento
    WHERE
        Name = BeneficiaryName
        AND GenderBeneficiary = 'Female'
        AND DateS BETWEEN @dateStart AND @dateEnd

    UNION

    SELECT
        COUNT (GenderBeneficiary)
    FROM
        CartaDescuento
    WHERE
        Name != BeneficiaryName
        AND GenderBeneficiary = 'Male'
        AND DateS BETWEEN @dateStart AND @dateEnd

    UNION

    SELECT
        COUNT (GenderBeneficiary)
    FROM
        CartaDescuento
    WHERE
        Name != BeneficiaryName
        AND GenderBeneficiary = 'Female'
        AND DateS BETWEEN @dateStart AND @dateEnd
END
```

The result:

```
Title
1
2
1
1
```

I'm calling the stored procedure from C# like this:

```
public void GetTableOne()
{
    string dateStart = dateInicio.Value.ToShortDateString();
    string dateEnd = dateFinal.Value.ToShortDateString();

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("FillTableOne", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dateStart", dateStart);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dateEnd", dateEnd);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "¡Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

**Updated:** but I only get 1 query, not the UNIONS in the stored procedure:

```
Title
1
```

**Updated:** I didn't put the query or the code, because that doesn't work. I'm looking for help in structuring that in a single query. I assumed that it was not necessary to put anything other than the tables and the result that I want, in this way to be able to accommodate the columns as the report requires.

Well, anyone know a better option to get in only **one** query?

Additional question: I'm reporting with iTextSharp and is kinda tedious typing 120 code lines to get and structure one simple table. Any suggestions on how to get a better reporter in C#?

Comment: mind providing us what SQL and/or C# code you have right now?  Hard to provide any help not knowing how your current code is structured, etc.  Side note - nothing wrong with using a couple unions if it's pulling back the data correctly.  Something tells me you're not calling the stored proc correctly/storing the results of it correctly, as 1 is usually what's returned on success of executing a `non-query`.

Comment: Don't know why... Because what I have doesn't work... I'm looking for a new Query that doesn't use UNION, or ideas to make the Query.
Anyway I update my ask!, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't exactly the structure you asked for but it gets back all of the data in one query:

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN Name != Beneficiary AND GenderBeneficiary= 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [FemaleFamiliars],
SUM(CASE WHEN Name != Beneficiary AND GenderBeneficiary= 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [MaleFamiliars],
SUM(CASE WHEN Name = Beneficiary AND GenderBeneficiary= 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [FemaleEmployees],
SUM(CASE WHEN Name = Beneficiary AND GenderBeneficiary= 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [MaleEmployees],
SUM(CASE WHEN GenderBeneficiary= 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [TotalFemales],
SUM(CASE WHEN GenderBeneficiary= 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [TotalMales],
SUM(CASE WHEN Name != Beneficiary THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [TotalFamiliar],
SUM(CASE WHEN Name = Beneficiary THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [TotalEmployees],
COUNT(*) AS [GrandTotal]
FROM Employees
```

Comment: SUM instead COUNT, that's a BIG mistake froma myself. This is the right answer. Thank you very much for your time and your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach to this. It requires two queries and a UNION ALL but not a huge deal. It is actually quite a few less characters than the previous answer. :)

```
declare @Something table
(
    Name varchar(10)
    , Beneficiary varchar(10)
    , GenderBeneficiary varchar(10)
)

insert @Something values
('Karla', 'Karla', 'Female')
,('Carl', 'Mandy', 'Female')
,('Mark', 'Lu', 'Male')
,('Erik', 'Math', 'Male')
,('Jhon', 'Jhon', 'Male')

select case when s.Name = s.Beneficiary then 'Employee' else 'Familiar' end
    , sum(case when GenderBeneficiary = 'Male' then 1 end)
    , sum(case when GenderBeneficiary = 'Female' then 1 end)
    , count(*)
from @Something s
group by case when s.Name = s.Beneficiary then 'Employee' else 'Familiar' end

UNION ALL

select Description = 'Total'
    , sum(case when GenderBeneficiary = 'Male' then 1 end)
    , sum(case when GenderBeneficiary = 'Female' then 1 end)
    , count(*)
from @Something s
```

Comment: uh... this is a nice one too! I can only mark one as right answer, by priority i'm gonna mark the @SBFrancies answer. But i'm appreciate your time!